# Почему обнуляется массив?

Tags: java, массивы, swing

На форме есть поле ввода, 2 кнопки и таблица. При вводе числа и нажатии на первую кнопку, введенное число сохраняется в массив. При нажатии на вторую кнопку должна заполняться таблица данными из массива. Но когда по нажатию второй кнопки обращаюсь к элементу массива - он содержит нули. Почему обнуляется массив? Может по невнимательности/незнанию что-то упустил, но не понимаю почему так происходит.

Код:

```
public class JFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form JFrame
     */
    public JFrame() {
        initComponents();
        // Массив, в который записываются введенные данные
        int array[][] = new int[255][13];
        int codeSymbol = 0;

        jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                int codeSymbol = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
                array[codeSymbol][0] = codeSymbol;
                System.out.println("Байт 1: " + array[codeSymbol][0]);
            }
        });
        jButton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                System.out.println("Столбец 1: " + array [codeSymbol][0] );
            }
        });
    }
/**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Байт 1");

        jButton1.setText("Сохранить");

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
                new Object [][] {
                        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null}
                },
                new String [] {
                        "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"
                }
        ) {
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                    false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false
            };

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);
        if (jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumnCount() > 0) {
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setResizable(false);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setResizable(false);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setResizable(false);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setResizable(false);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setResizable(false);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setResizable(false);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setResizable(false);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(9).setResizable(false);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(10).setResizable(false);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(11).setResizable(false);
        }

        jButton2.setText("Ввод");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                .addGap(80, 80, 80)
                                                                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 113, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                                .addComponent(jButton1))
                                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                .addGap(161, 161, 161)
                                                                .addComponent(jButton2)))
                                                .addGap(0, 67, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addContainerGap()
                                                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(jButton1))
                                .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 170, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 54, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(jButton2)
                                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
     */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new JFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы объявляете локальную переменную

```
 int codeSymbol = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

которая прекратит существования после выхода из метода, вместо того, чтобы использовать поле класса, как, например,

```
 codeSymbol = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
 ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: я бы добавил, что переменная `codeSymbol ` и массив `array` ограничиваются областью видимости конструктора, и нужно их вынести в поля класса

Comment: @MrFylypenko Это и так ясно. На то это и локальная переменная, а не поле класса.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, спасибо! Элементарные вещи и не заметил.

Comment: @Ivan Не за что.:)